# inscription on Chagall's "White Crucifixion"?

Tags: translation, christianity, language, aleph-bet-letters

What does the inscription on Chagall's painting *White Crucifixion* say?

[image: closeup of inscription]

Isn't [John 19:19](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=19&l=19-#x) ("Jesus of Nazareth, King of the Jews") written [ישוע הנצרי ומלך היהודים](https://forums.catholic.com/t/crucifix-with-3-languages-not-abbrev-inri/146960) in Hebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ישו הנוצרי, Yeshu hanotzri (not Yeshua) part is Hebrew; the rest is Aramaic: מלכא דיהדאי, malkah d'Yahadai.

---

Some more info can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4101588).